# using bamboo to chain together docker containers in a pipeline

Tags: docker, dockerfile, continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm using Bamboo 9.0 to build docker containers from a dockerfile. The first build plan is the production environment of some application. This build plan completes successfully and is configured to save the resulting docker image as `prod_img.tar` as an artifact.
The second build plan starts with `prod_img.tar` and adds C++ compiler, cmake, etc.. it is the build environment for some application.

How do I configure bamboo to take the artifact `prod_img.tar` from build plan 1 and make it available as the base for a dev environment container in build plan 2?

Build Plan 2 is triggered on completion of build plan 1 (the production docker image) and is configured to check out a dockerfile from Git

[image: download application production environment docker image]

Next, I try to supply `prod_img.tar` to Build Plan 2
[image: build the application build environment docker image]

The dockerfile in Build Plan 2 should use the `--build_arg` to start with `FROM prod_img.tar`.

```
## [Choice] define only the registry to pull the production image from
ARG REPOSITORY=my_local_repository:9999
## [Choice] define only the production image 
ARG BASE=my_production_image
## [Choice] define only the version of the production environment container to use as a base
ARG VARIANT=latest
## [Choice] fully define the base image
ARG BASE_IMAGE=${REPOSITORY}/${BASE}:${VARIANT}
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
USER root

# go on to install compiler, cmake, etc...
```

This fails because `prod_img.tar` isn't in any docker registry.
How should I tell bamboo to chain the result of Build Plan 1 to the input of Build Plan 2?
Is there some reliable way to use `docker load` for this?